# Log in page in flutter

Tags: flutter

I created a login page in flutter, but there is a problem 
when I click on the text field the field is Hiding under the keyboard,,,
can anyone solve m problem??

I need to create a login page similar to the Facebook page

**this is the login page in normal,**

https://i.ibb.co/w4w2V7s/1.jpg

**and this is the page when I click on any text field,**

https://i.ibb.co/PhBZcLg/2.jpg

thank you for helping

Comment: I didn't get what you need, Can you explain what you need clearly

Comment: what have you tried so far? And what is the problem you encountered?

Comment: I want to create the login page, but I need when the keyboard appears the screen make zoom on the text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ListView Widget to scroll vertically the Column with the TextFields when you focus them.

Comment: I want to create the login page, but I need when the keyboard appears the screen make zoom on the text field ,,,,

Comment: You can put the TextField into AnimatedPositioned into a Stack